# Tasker - read the ping time

Tags: tasker

we can use ping shell command in tasker to see if a domain is online or not but can we get the ping time too?
like in pc when you ping that shows a "time=xx" can we somehow access to that in tasker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A1: Run Shell [ Command:ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 Timeout (Seconds):0 Use Root:Off Store Output In:%PING Store Errors In: Store Result In: Continue Task After Error:On ] 


A2: Variable Section [ Name:%PING From:88 Length:11 Adapt To Fit:Off Store Result In:%TEST ] 


A3: Flash [ Text:%TEST Long:On ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the response times like this:

`ping -qc1 google.com 2>&1 | awk -F'/' 'END{ print (/^rtt/? "OK "$5" ms":"FAIL") }'`

Example output: `OK 1.038 ms`

You could modify the output to get only the numeric value, so the output can be directly piped to a variable in tasker, eg:
`ping -qc1 google.com 2>&1 | awk -F'/' 'END{ print (/^rtt/? $5 : 0) }'`

Exmaple output: `1.038` or in case of a failure: `0`

__

credits: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409203/ping-show-only-results